# Examples of transitive geodesic flows that are not ergodic

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

What would be an easy example of a transitive geodesic flow (defined as: there is a geodesic whose velocity vectors are dense on the unit tangent bundle) that is not ergodic?

**Motivation.** A well-known theorem of Hedlund and Morse states that the geodesic flow of a Riemannian metric without conjugate points in a closed surfaces of genus greater than one is transitive. However, I've never seen it mentioned whether such flow is necessarily ergodic (unlike the case for metrics of negative curvature), and I have never seen it explicitly mentioned whether it was not known or just not true.